# How to associate a file with a newly installed app on tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, file-format

How to associate a particular type of file with a newly installed app on the tablet ("Open with...")? I would like to open .epub files with Beru app automatically but I cannot find the way how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For a particular mime types default handling application you'd want to look in

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

This file contains the default applications for all handled mime types.

If an application isn't configured to open a file at all (not only as the default application for that type of file), you'd need to look in its desktop entry in

```
/usr/share/applications
```

To add it where appropriate. These desktop files are also used in the defaults.list, where the format is:

handlerType/fileMetaType=desktopentry.desktop

handlerType is the type of handler, e.g a binary file will have "application" because it will be specific to an application, while a common mp4 file would have "video" as the mime type, a text file "text", and so on. The fileMetaType is the specific file type, such as a pdf of binary format which would have the fileMetaType of "pdf". desktopentry.desktop is simply the desktop entry of the file you're using to open that application. These terms are probably not what are widely used, but I'm using them to hopefully better explain what the things mean. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, XtrmJosh. The procedure seems too complicated for me, though. I am not an expert and I am afraid I could change something inappropriately with undesired consequences. Or, alternatively, could you post a detailed sequence of steps how to solve my concrete problem with epub files and Beru app?

Comment: OK, first step if you can, open a terminal emulator, navigate using cd in the terminal to a folder which contains an epub file, and run `file --mime-type -b filename` - I'll need the output of this to see how the mime type corresponds to what lives in the defaults.list file. Once you've provided this I can talk you through step by step how to set it up. You might have to install an app for it, and I believe the app is called "Terminal" (should be free and released by Ubuntu Core App Developers).

Comment: I'll also need to know if there is a file called something like Beru.desktop in the folder /usr/share/applications (you might need to do something like `cd /usr/share/applications && ls -l | grep beru` or even just `cd /usr/share/applications && ls -ltr` and see if you can see it.

Comment: The mime type is: application/epub+zip. There is no Beru.desktop file in the application folder. Btw, I can't see the defaults.list file in the application folder but I can see it in the Open file dialog of Gedit. However Gedit doesn't support onscreen keyboard  so it is useless without the external one.

Comment: Ah, do you have a file manager and a text editor that you can use? If so, you can use them. You'll need to find out the command to launch Beru (presumably just "Beru" in a terminal will do, and create a file called beru.desktop, then add `application/epub+zip=beru.desktop` to the defaults.list. Is the defaults.list file empty in gedit? If so, it's automatically creating a new file for you and your default file associations are elsewhere...

Comment: On the way home from work I also realised, you could use Ubuntu Tweak (if it's available for tablet, I think it is?) or even mimeopen (terminal application). For mimeopen, you can just run `mimeopen -d file.epub` and it will prompt you which viewer you want to use as default. If Beru appears in the list, just type the number along side it and you're golden.

Comment: I don't know how to launch Beru in terminal (simple "beru" does't work). I realized that Gedit is running in Puritine container so it doesn't have an access to Utouch files and what I see in Gedit dialog are folders/files of the container. Probably, there is even no defaults.list file in the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I solved as follows:
- Right click on the file
- Select "Properties"
- Select tab "Open With"
- Select the application you want to open with
- Click "Add"

That's all